# Grouping Consecutive Rows in DB2

Tags: sql, database, group-by, db2

I have a table in DB2 that looks like the following:-

```
ID        DESCRIPTION        TYPE    AMOUNT
--        -----------        ----    ------
1         Item 1             ONE     100
2         Item 2             ONE     50    
3         Item 3             TWO     100
4         Item 4             TWO     50
5         Item 5             ONE     100
6         Item 6             TWO     50
7         Item 7             ONE     100
8         Item 8             TWO     50
9         Item 9             TWO     100
10        Item 10            ONE     50
```

I want to group consecutive rows with the same type so it looks like the following:-

```
TYPE    AMOUNT
----    ------
ONE        150            -- (ID 1,2)
TWO        150            -- (ID 3,4)
ONE        100            -- (ID 5)
TWO        50             -- (ID 6)
ONE        100            -- (ID 7)
TWO        150            -- (ID 8,9)
ONE        50             -- (ID 10)
```

Note the last column is just to denote which Id's are in the rollup.

I'd rather do this with a query than a Stored Procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This appears to be a fairly standard [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem.  Most of the "standard" solutions for other dbs should work here as well - primarily you need to generate the "grouping" similarly to what I do [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6630296/812837).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse what made this problem a little more difficult (I posted an answer below) is that his groups are based on changes in a value of a column, but subsequent groups can have the same values as previous groups (but they need to be different groups). Therefore partitioning on TYPE (the field that determines the group, in this case) will not work, because it will continue numbering based on values in previous groups.

Comment: In other words there are only two unique values of TYPE but the result needs to be 7 groups, due to changes determined by order of id. A combination of row_number() over and lag (to look for changes and start a rownumber at each change) is what worked for me. Using only row_number over() with a partition on type will give you only 2 groups, as there are only two values in the TYPE column (in this sample)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia - I think you need to re-read that answer again, where I explain what's going on.  The answer here can be a **lot** simpler than what you're trying.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I miss my guess, this can be trivially done with a double-`ROW_NUMBER()` constant expression:

```
SELECT type, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM (SELECT type, amount, id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) 
                          - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id) AS groupId
      FROM tbl) grouped
GROUP BY groupId, type
ORDER BY groupId, MIN(id)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662ac/58/0)</kbd>
(Thanks to Brian for the initial fiddle setup)

...which yields the desired results.  Note that `MIN(id)` is required to ensure a consistent sort order - `groupId` is not universally unique, so otherwise some `ONE` or `TWO` rows can end up flipped.

As a side note, I dislike ordering on an `id` column, as the only thing such an id is really good for is *uniqueness*.  This is especially true in cases where rows may be updated or otherwise reinterpreted - do you have something like an `insertedAt` timestamp you could use for ordering instead?

Comment: +1 for simplicity... I did not think of using two row_number()s like that :/

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it:

**[Fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662ac/51/0)**

```
with sub1 as
 (select x.*,
         case when chk is not null
              then row_number() over(order by id)
              else null
              end as rn
    from (select id,
                 description,
                 type,
                 amount,
                 case when lag(type, 1) over(order by id) <> type
                      then 'X'
                      else null
                      end as chk
            from tbl
           order by id) x)
select min(type),
       sum(amount) as amount,
       listagg(id, ', ') within group(order by id) as ids
  from (select z.id, z.description, z.type, z.amount, y.rn
          from sub1 z
         cross join sub1 y
         where z.rn is null
           and y.rn = (select max(x.rn)
                         from sub1 x
                        where x.id < z.id
                          and x.rn is not null)
        union all
        select id, description, type, amount, rn
          from sub1
         where rn is not null
        union all
        select id, description, type, amount, 1
          from sub1
         where id < (select min(id) from sub1 where rn is not null)
         order by id) x
 group by rn
 order by rn
```

I tested it in Oracle but it just relies on the with clause and window functions which I believe DB2 has so it should work, if anything with minor modifications.